# no declaration can be found for element 'int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter'

Tags: java, spring-integration

Spring-integration-kafka - 
    I am creating Spring-integration-kakfa application but while startup it  gives me error, please find below error stack -

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 24; columnNumber: 110; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:452)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3230)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1911)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:740)
```

I can find couple of example with Java based configuration but need XML based configuration for Kafka producer and consumer. Can anyone please help me on this ?

kafka-inbound-channel.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-kafka="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/ 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <int:channel id="inputFromKafka">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="kafkaMessageExecutor" />
    </int:channel>

    <task:executor id="kafkaMessageExecutor" pool-size="0-10"
        keep-alive="120" queue-capacity="500" />

    <int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter kafka-consumer-context-ref="consumerContext" channel="inputFromKafka">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="10" />
    </int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int-kafka:consumer-context id="consumerContext"
        consumer-timeout="4000" zookeeper-connect="zookeeperConnect">
        <int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
            <int-kafka:consumer-configuration
                group-id="default" value-decoder="deccoder" key-decoder="deccoder"
                max-messages="5000">
                <int-kafka:topic id="FppTopic1" streams="4" />
                <int-kafka:topic id="FppTopic2" streams="4" />
            </int-kafka:consumer-configuration>
        </int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
    </int-kafka:consumer-context>

    <int-kafka:zookeeper-connect id="zookeeperConnect" 
                          zk-connect="sd-dc1b-b0ce:2181"
                          zk-connection-timeout="6000"
                          zk-session-timeout="6000"
                          zk-sync-time="2000"/>

    <bean id="deccoder" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.common.StringDecoder" />

</beans>
```

Other configuration is plain Spring MVC application configuration in dispatcher servlet importing resource as 'kafka-inbound-channle.xml' but after import statement it gives this error

Answer (score 0):

You should show your XML config, indeed. Otherwise it is really hard to help just having a coffee dust.

You can find some samples in the project's tests: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/kafka/config/xml

On the other hand, sometimes this is an error in the IDE. Consider to use Spring-compliant one. For example IntelliJ IDEA or STS.

Comment: updated my question with kafka configuration file that I am using

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have checked given url but it has all java configuration but I need XML based configuration, Can you please help me on this ?

Comment: Well, try to use ` http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka-1.0.xsd` without version, like all other schema locations. And on the other hand why do you use so old Spring Integration Kafka? That `1.0` is for ancient Apache Kafka.

Comment: I have tried without version like http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka.xsd but still same issue.

Comment: Is it runtime error or just a warn from IDE before compilation and assembling?

Comment: It is runtime error, while running application it loads dispatcher-servlet.xml while loading it contains import resource - kafka-inbound-channle.xml which gives error.

Comment: Ok. So you don’t have an appropriate `spring-integration-Kafka` jar at run time